# mysql_real_escape_string and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Let say i have a column product name and it has value `Shoe's`.
When i pick that value from db and use `mysql_real_escape_string` and placed it in html hidden input it becomes `<input type='hidden' value='Shoe\'s' id='product_name'>`

When i do `$('#product_name').val()` it return only `Shoe\` truncating the `s` or rest of the value after that. The jQuery is assuming an escaped single quote as a closing quote for attr value.

On solution is to use `value=""` (enclosed in double quotes) but what if value contains a double quote? So the problem persists.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `mysql_real_escape_string` for values you are putting into HTML?!

Comment: you should use mysql_real_escape_string when you save things in the database, not when you fetch them.. that until you switch to a better option like pdo as the man page shows http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: First of all this is the db provided to me by my employer, this is not the way i set the things up, these came to me by him. Considering that mysql_real_escape_string was not used when storing values in db. Now what should i do?

Comment: You need to learn what "escaping" actually means: [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: that function escapes the parameters, if it is not used when you save data that's a different issue, than doesn't mean that you should use it when you select data.. you already have two good answers pointing you to htmlspecialchars, check if that is what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not use `mysql_real_escape_string` for HTML output. Use the appropriate [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, a backslash before a quote does not mean that the quote is escaped. An escaped `'` in HTML is `&#039;`. That's why you use *the appropriate escaping method* for your output target. `mysql_real_escape_string` is appropriate when escaping for SQL, [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is appropriate when escaping for HTML.